# Can I catch 404s in a service worker?

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

Basically, I have an online app that uses a htaccess file to silently redirect all requests in a given /folder/ to the same html. Then, to decide what to show the user, the page calls

```
var page_name = location.href.split('/').pop();
```

This works well online, but could I use a ServiceWorker to support this folder/file model while the page is offline? Or will I always get the page cannot be found error unless I explicitly cache the URLs?

Comment: Just to clarify—you want to serve the same HTML "shell" in response to all navigations, and then in that shell HTML, you want to ensure that the "real" URL is available via `location.href` so that you can do client-side routing to populate the URL-specific content?

Comment: That's it! The minimal example here is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe can be accomplished using the [App Shell model](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/11/app-shell).

Your service worker's exact code might look a little different, and tools like [Workbox](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/06/pwa-webpack-workbox/) can automate some of this for you, but a very basic, "vanilla" example of a service worker that accomplishes this is:

```
self.addEvenListener('install', (event) => {
  const cacheShell = async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open('my-cache');
    await cache.add('/shell.html');
  };

  event.waitUntil(cacheShell());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // If this is a navigation request...
  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    // ...respond with the cached shell HTML.
    event.respondWith(caches.match('/shell.html'));
    return;
  }

  // Any other caching/response logic can go here.
});
```

Regardless of what the `location.href` value is, when this service worker is in control, the App Shell HTML will be used to fulfill all navigation requests.